# Change xml value using linq in c#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, linq

I am working on this since the past 2 hours.I have an XML file which looks like this

```
<catalog>
  <captureInfo>
    <row>5</row>
    <col>5</col>
  </captureInfo>

  <patientInfo>
    <name>XYZ</name>
    <detail>details here</detail>
  </patientInfo>

  <imageData>
    <r0c0>
      <contrastFlag>true</contrastFlag>
    </r0c0>
  <imageData>
<catalog>
```

I want to change the value of contrastFlag. I tried this but its not working

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filename)
xdoc.Element("catalog")
                .Element("imageData")
                .Descendants()
                .Where(x => x.Value == "r0c0")
                .First()
                .SetElementValue("contrastFlag", "newValue");


            doc.Save("XMLFile1.xml");
```

Can I know where I am going wrong and what would be the correct approach?

Comment: Change where condition to `x.Name == "r0c0"`

Comment: i get this error - "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: the `<imageData>` and `<catalog>` tags are not closed properly, but after that is fixed, this works for me `xdoc.Element("catalog").Element("imageData").Element("r0c0").SetElementValue("contrastFlag", "newValue");`

Comment: From : .Where(x => x.Value == "r0c0") To: .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "r0c0")

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if you have multiple `contrastFlag` elements or not.

If there's only one, you can simply do this:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
var element = xdoc.Root.Descendants("contrastFlag").FirstOrDefault();
if (element != null)
    element.Value = "false";
xdoc.Save("sample1.xml");
```

If you have multiple elements, you can use `XPath` instead:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
var element = xdoc.Root.XPathSelectElement("//catalog//imageData//r0c0//contrastFlag");
if (element != null)
    element.Value = "false";
xdoc.Save("sample1.xml");
```

---

**NOTE:**

`XPath` is in `using System.Xml.XPath` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
.Where(x => x.Name == "r0c0")
```

Changed to this instead of x.Value because its an element Name.